# Parameters not passing into mySQL/PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

If I use the following query it works perfect:

```
function stream4($barName, $fbookID) {
    $result = query("SELECT SUM(barName ='the bar') as totalBars FROM overallLikes WHERE fbookID='11229344'",$barName, $fbookID);

 }
```

BUT if I use the following I get 0 as a result:

```
function stream4($barName, $fbookID) {
    $result = query("SELECT SUM(barName ='%s') as totalBars FROM overallLikes WHERE fbookID='%s'",$barName, $fbookID);
}
```

I set the first function above with literal values (works perfect) and the second function above I am trying to pass parameters (get 0).  The result is not supposed to be 0.

The switch statement Im using in my index.php file is as follows:

case "stream4":
        stream4((int)$_POST['barName'], $_POST['fbookID']);
        break;

Thanks

Comment: What does `query()` look like?

Comment: should that not be `LIKE`

Comment: `query()` is not a native function of PHP, which library are you using?

Comment: I don't think the OP is going for `LIKE`. It looks like an attempt to bind parameters/values. Is this PDO? Mysqli?

Comment: the query looks like this: totalBars = 0. This is standard query for PHP with mySQL database and works for all other queries.

Comment: Try `?` in place of `%s`

Comment: `query()` is a function that you created?

the variables `$barName` and `$fbookID` have content? Try to give them `echo $variable`, before adding them to the `query`.

Comment: what should be the return type of query? is this the function that you're using?　http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Yes fbookID is a string

Comment: The return type of the query should be a number since its counting the instances of a barname where the fbookID is whatever is passed in. The query is what is used with AFNetworking API calls to return data from the mySQL database. Both barName and fbookID are strings.

Comment: and yes...fbookID and barName have content coming from the API call (iOS program). These are supposed to come in with values from the program.

Comment: I have an index.php file with a switch statement to bring in the paramters. case "stream4":
  stream4((int)$_POST['barName'], $_POST['fbookID']);
  break;

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement I was using has (int) in the settings. I removed this and now it works. Thanks everyone.